# The replacement of worldToIntrinsic function in R2012a or below

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

MATLAB: the replacement of [worldToIntrinsic function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imref2d.worldtointrinsic.html?searchHighlight=imref) in R2012a or below

As it is known to all, the function in discussion available only in R2013a or later, so

Any replaceable build-in functions or home-make approaches are good.

Edit: I don't have imref2d class, yet have [world coordinate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html#brcu_cr) issue introduced by function imtransform

What we have is the xdata and ydata from below:

```
[ output, xdata, ydata ] = imtransform( imgDouble{1}, tform );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Trying to understand what you are really trying to do here. As I understand it the function is useful when you have defined "world" and "intrinsic" coordinates through the `imref2d` class. You don't have any of that available... so I don't think your image has properties to be read. Put differently - your problem is bigger than "replace this function"... could you think more carefully about what you are trying to do, and re-phrase the question?

Comment: @Floris Thank you, I don't have imref2d class, yet have world coordinate issue introduced by function imtransform What we have is the xdata and ydata from below: [ output, xdata, ydata ] = imtransform( imgDouble{1}, tform );

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if you have the function `imtransform` available to you, you should simply compute the inverse transform (that is, the inverse of `tform`) in order to be able to compute the transform "in the other direction". If you start reading up about the `imtransform` function, and the related functions `maketform` and `tformfwd` and `tforminv`, I think you will be able to figure it out. I don't have access to a Matlab environment right now or I would run some tests for you - but I'm 90% sure that these functions will help you get to a solution yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What is the world coordinate issue you have after calling imtransform? The XData/YData ouputs, and UData/VData/Size Name/Value inputs are the functional equivalent to the use of imref2d in terms of referencing an image grid to a world coordinate system.

If what you are interested in is the point transformations in a forward/inverse sense implied by your geometric transformation, then you can use the functions tformfwd/tforminv. Its hard to know how to answer this question without knowing the problem you are trying to solve.

- Alex