# The code working not properly

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I am a beginner in Matlab. I tried to run this Matlab code of the project "Image Mosaic Using Speeded Up Robust Feature Detection" and these are the errors that came up.

```
clear workspace
clear;
clc;
close all;
%//read Reference image and convert into single
rgb1= im2single(imread('r1.jpg'));
I1 = rgb2gray(rgb1);
%//create mosaic background
sz= size(I1)+300;% Size of the mosaic
h=sz(1);
w=sz(2);
%//create a world coordinate system
outputView = imref2d([h,w]);
%//affine matrix
xtform = eye(3);
%// Warp the current image onto the mosaic image
%//using 2D affine geometric transformation
mosaic = imwarp(rgb1, affine2d(xtform),'OutputView', outputView);
figure,imshow(mosaic,'initialmagnification','fit');
%//read Target image and convert into single
rgb2= im2single(imread('t1.jpg'));
I2 = rgb2gray(rgb2);
%//find surf features of reference and target image ,then find new 
%//affine matrix
%//Detect SURFFeatures in the reference image
points = detectSURFFeatures(I1);
%//detectSURFFeatures returns information about SURF features detected 
%//in the 2-D grayscale input image . The detectSURFFeatures function 
%//implements the Speeded-Up Robust Features (SURF) algorithm 
%//to find blob features
%//Extract feature vectors, also known as descriptors, and their 
%//corresponding locations
[featuresPrev, pointsPrev] = extractFeatures(I1,points);
%//Detect SURFFeatures in the target image
points = detectSURFFeatures(I2);
%//Extract feature vectors and their corresponding locations
[features, points] = extractFeatures(I2,points); 
%// Match features computed from the refernce and the target images
indexPairs = matchFeatures(features, featuresPrev);  
%// Find corresponding locations in the refernce and the target images
matchedPoints     = points(indexPairs(:, 1), :);
matchedPointsPrev = pointsPrev(indexPairs(:, 2), :);  
%//compute a geometric transformation from the  corresponding locations
tform=estimateGeometricTransform(matchedPoints,matchedPointsPrev,'affine');
%//get affine matrix
xtform = tform.T;
%// Warp the current image onto the mosaic image
mosaicnew = imwarp(rgb2, affine2d(xtform), 'OutputView', outputView);
figure,imshow(mosaicnew,'initialmagnification','fit');
%//create a object to overlay one image over another
halphablender = vision.AlphaBlender('Operation', 'Binary mask', 'MaskSource', 'Input port');
%// Creat a mask which specifies the region of the target image.
%// BY Applying geometric transformation to image
mask= imwarp(ones(size(I2)), affine2d(xtform), 'OutputView', outputView)>=1;
figure,imshow(mask,'initialmagnification','fit');
%//overlays one image over another
mosaicfinal = step(halphablender, mosaic,mosaicnew, mask);
%// %show results
figure,imshow(rgb1,'initialmagnification','fit');
figure,imshow(rgb2,'initialmagnification','fit');
figure,imshow(mosaicfinal,'initialmagnification','fit');
```

Error:

```
"Undefined function 'imref2d' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in immosaic (line 13)
outputView = imref2d([h,w]);
```

Please assist me with the correct code.

Comment: While having absolutely no clue of matlab, the error sggests you provide erroneous parameters to the function imref2d([h,w]);. It seems to take a height ans width, which may be integer, but you provided a double sized number. Have a look at that. You might need to round the result of this here: sz= size(I1)+300;% Size of the mosaic

Comment: 2 Questions: (1) put a breakpoint at line 13, run your code to that point, print out the values of `h` and `w` in the command line and report them back here. (2) do you have the image processing toolbox installed? type `ver` in the command line to check

Comment: @KaiMattern, in Matlab this error message actually suggests that the function isn't there at all. Rarely does it mean that you gave the wrong arguments, and here there should be no problem regarding double/ints.

Answer (score 4):

If you search for `imref2d` you find this [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/imref2d-class.html) on the Matlab website. This is a very strong indication that you don't have the *Image Processing Toolbox* available. You should check this using `ver`.

Generally speaking and as @Sheldon pointed out, this often means that the function can't be found by Matlab. In this case and where you have the function because it was provided in some package that you downloaded, either copy it to where you need it, OR, use `addpath('path/to/function')` to tell Matlab where to find the function.

Answer (score 4):

The spatial referencing object imref2d was introduced in the R2013a release of the Image Processing Toolbox. I think its a time for Matlab upgrade!!

Comment: Is there any function available in 2012a instead of imref2d?

Comment: i dont know exactly but the following post should help you i guess! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693510/the-replacement-of-worldtointrinsic-function-in-r2012a-or-below

Answer (score 1):

This error is telling you the the function imref2d does not exist.

I'm assuming that you got the code for this project from somewhere else and are missing a file. Make sure that you copied all of the code and files correctly.